# ExecuteNonQuery CommandText property has not been initialized

Tags: c#, executenonquery

When I click on this button, I face with this error:

> executenonquery commandtext property has not been initialized

```
private void button_FirstStep_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection(Yahya.strcon);
    Conn.Open();
    int CurrentCount = Convert.ToInt32(label_CurrentCount.Text);
    string strcom1 = "select * from vm1 where count = '" + (CurrentCount - 1) + "' and benchmarkid = '" + Structure.BenchmarkID + "' ";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strcom1, Conn);
    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    string strcom = "";
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        if (reader["vmid"].ToString() != "")
        {
            string vmid = reader["vmid"].ToString();
            strcom += "update vm1 set pmid = (select pmid from vm1 as VM2  where   benchmarkid = '" + Structure.BenchmarkID + "' and  vm2.count ='" + (CurrentCount - 1) + "' and vm2.vmid ='" + vmid + "' ) where count  =  '" + CurrentCount + "'  and vmid = '" + vmid + "' and  benchmarkid = '" + Structure.BenchmarkID + "'  \n";
        }
    }//end of while
    reader.Close();
    cmd.CommandText = strcom;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: Did you debug it? How many rows were returned from by `ExecuteReader`? If there were no results, `reader.Read` was never `true` so `strcom` is still empty.

Comment: [Bobby Tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work) is coming to this party and he says that he brings lot of friends

Comment: also, you make a point of casting currentCount to an int, then treat it as a varchar in the query by surrounding it in quotes - is Count in vb1 numerical?  If so, drop the quotes (or better still parameterise the queries)

Answer (score 2):

Rene is quite right about his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35361511/executenonquery-commandtext-property-has-not-been-initialized#comment58429049_35361511), looks like your `reader.Read()` returns `false` and that's why your code *never* goes into your `while` loop and your `CommandText` is assigned to `""`, that's why `ExecuteNonQuery` throws

> ExecuteNonQuery: CommandText property has not been initialized

You can check your strcom is empty string or not to solve your problem but I see **more** wrong things in your code other than that..

- Looks like your `count` column is numeric value but you supplied your `CurrentCount - 1` as a character with single quotes. If it is not numeric, it **should**. Read: [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type)
- Based on it's name, `benchmarkid` should(?) be numeric types as well.
- You can solve this two problem with using [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/) because this kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.
- Use [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your connection, command and reader *automatically* instead of calling `Close` or `Dispose` methods manually.
- `Open` your connection *just* before you execute your command.

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this by simply debugging before asking.

The reason for this error is presumably that your first request returns zero results.
So `reader.Read()` is always `false` and `strcom` stays empty. You set an empty string as `cmd.CommandText` before the call to `ExecuteNonQuery()`.

To solve this, simply check if the string is empty and execute the last query only if it is not empty:

```
...
reader.Close();
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strcom))
{
    cmd.CommandText = strcom;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```